# Firebase function storing datetime as map

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase functions setup to create a new event in the firestore db with the onCall method. I am passing data to the onCall method from my frontend vue app. The data that i want to set in the database contains a bunch of data, with it a few Dates that need to be saved. The dates are future date/times and once they get added to the firestore db, they show as type `map` instead of `timestamp`

My firebase-admin version is 8.0.0 and firebase-functions version is 3.0.0

This adds the data to the collection but the timestamp is now in the `map` type with nanoseconds and seconds. How can this be made to save in the `Timestamp` type??

Frontend js call to onCall:

```
let data = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  startDate: myStartDate  // This is a JS date object - Fri Aug 30 2019 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
};
return db.httpsCallable('myFunction')({ myData: data });
```

Backend Google Function:

```
exports.myFunction= functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const myData = data.myData;
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('myCollection')
    .doc('myDocument')
    .collection('myAccount')
    .add({ ...myData  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a callable function, all the type information in the input object is going to be completely stripped of type information before it's sent to the function.  It will be serialized as JSON, which is just objects, arrays, numbers, strings, booleans, and nulls.  The timestamp will be serialized as seconds and nanos, because that's how it's represented internally.

If you want to send a timestamp to a callable function, your function should be prepared to receive seconds and nanos, and [create a new Timestamp object](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html) with those values before passing them to the Firebase Admin SDK, which will interpret it correctly.

Comment: On the frontend do i still need to use firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(startDate) before sending it to the onCall method?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to send data to your backend for processing.  You don't have to create a Timestamp on the client if you don't want.  You could just send the Date millis value and convert it in the function.

Comment: Perfect, yes that's what i just did and it worked. Thanks Doug